# Does ggplot depend on unclass values or group values in ggplot_build()$data[[1]]?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is something I encountered yesterday when I was answering one of the questions on SO. This was a very confusing issue to me. I took a day and now I think my idea is clear. Due to the nature of the issue, my post will be long. My apology.

```
foo <- data.frame(split = rep(c("0", "1"), each = 5),
         a = rep(1:5,2), 
         b = c(7,8,9,10,11,6,8,9,10,12),
         x = c(1:5, 1:5),
         y = c(1:3,5,6,1.1,2.1,4.1,5.1,7.1),
         stringsAsFactors=F)
```

This is the sample data from the question I dealt with. In the question, I had to draw lines and points. Then, I experienced something I do not understand. Let me explain.

**STORY**

In this data frame, the OP treated split as factor and drew figures like these. I checked the following. In $ split,zero has 1 in `unclass()`, and one has 2 in `unclass()`.

```
foo$split <- as.factor(foo$split)

#> str(foo)
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ split: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
# $ a    : int  1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
# $ b    : num  7 8 9 10 11 6 8 9 10 12
# $ x    : int  1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
# $ y    : num  1 2 3 5 6 1.1 2.1 4.1 5.1 7.1
```

Then, I drew figures. What the OP wanted was to see points and line for the 1 (in split) group appear on top of those for the 0 (in split) group. But, the following attempt failed. Red points and line should be on top of the green points and line.

```
p <- ggplot(data = foo, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = split))+
     geom_point(size = 6) +
     ggtitle("p")

p2 <- ggplot(data = foo, aes(x = a, y = b, colour = split))+
      geom_line() +
      ggtitle("p2")

png(filename = "pic1.png", width = 900, height = 600)
grid.arrange(p, p2, ncol = 1)
dev.off()
```

[image]

I also looked into `ggplot_build()$data[[1]]` to see what data ggplot used. The 0 group had the value of 1 in `group`, and I thought ggplot used the values as an order to draw points and line given the outcomes in p and p1.

```
ana <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]] 

#    colour x   y PANEL group
#1  #F8766D 1 1.0     1     1
#2  #F8766D 2 2.0     1     1
#3  #F8766D 3 3.0     1     1
#4  #F8766D 4 5.0     1     1
#5  #F8766D 5 6.0     1     1
#6  #00BFC4 1 1.1     1     2
#7  #00BFC4 2 2.1     1     2
#8  #00BFC4 3 4.1     1     2
#9  #00BFC4 4 5.1     1     2
#10 #00BFC4 5 7.1     1     2

bob <- ggplot_build(p2)$data[[1]] 

#    colour x  y PANEL group
#1  #F8766D 1  7     1     1
#2  #F8766D 2  8     1     1
#3  #F8766D 3  9     1     1
#4  #F8766D 4 10     1     1
#5  #F8766D 5 11     1     1
#6  #00BFC4 1  6     1     2
#7  #00BFC4 2  8     1     2
#8  #00BFC4 3  9     1     2
#9  #00BFC4 4 10     1     2
#10 #00BFC4 5 12     1     2
```

So, the OP's option was to reorder the factor levels in split. I thought this was the right direction. Here, note that 0 and 1 are reordered. But the values in `unclass()` still the original.

```
foo$split <- ordered(foo$split, rev(levels(foo$split)))

#> str(foo)
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ split: Ord.factor w/ 2 levels "1"<"0": 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1
# $ a    : int  1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
# $ b    : num  7 8 9 10 11 6 8 9 10 12
# $ x    : int  1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
# $ y    : num  1 2 3 5 6 1.1 2.1 4.1 5.1 7.1

p3 <- ggplot(data = foo, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = split))+
      geom_point(size = 6) +
      ggtitle("p3")

p4 <- ggplot(data = foo, aes(x = a, y = b, colour = split))+
      geom_line() +
      ggtitle("p4")

png(filename = "pic2.png", width = 900, height = 600)
grid.arrange(p3, p4, ncol = 1)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Please note that colours are reversed after reordering the factor (split). As you see, this attempt was successful for the line graph (i.e., p4) since you see the greenish colour being on top of the reddish line. But, this is not the case for p3. This is the puzzle I have. I looked into `ggplot_build()$data[[1]]` as well. The difference is that colours and the group values were reversed after reordering the factor level of split. Since the 0 group (0 in split) has the value of 2, I thought `ggplot` would draw the lines and points for the 0 group in the 2nd place. But this prediction was not necessarily correct.

```
cathy <- ggplot_build(p3)$data[[1]] 

#    colour x   y PANEL group
#1  #00BFC4 1 1.0     1     2
#2  #00BFC4 2 2.0     1     2
#3  #00BFC4 3 3.0     1     2
#4  #00BFC4 4 5.0     1     2
#5  #00BFC4 5 6.0     1     2
#6  #F8766D 1 1.1     1     1
#7  #F8766D 2 2.1     1     1
#8  #F8766D 3 4.1     1     1
#9  #F8766D 4 5.1     1     1
#10 #F8766D 5 7.1     1     1

dan <- ggplot_build(p4)$data[[1]] 

#    colour x  y PANEL group
#1  #00BFC4 1  7     1     2
#2  #00BFC4 2  8     1     2
#3  #00BFC4 3  9     1     2
#4  #00BFC4 4 10     1     2
#5  #00BFC4 5 11     1     2
#6  #F8766D 1  6     1     1
#7  #F8766D 2  8     1     1
#8  #F8766D 3  9     1     1
#9  #F8766D 4 10     1     1
#10 #F8766D 5 12     1     1
```

At this moment, my guess is that ggplot used the group value in `ggolot_build()$data[[1]]` for the line graph whereas it used the values in `unclass()` to draw the point graph. In order to test this hypothesis, I did the following. I purposely gave 2 (in `unclass()`) to 0 (in split). I called the original data frame, foo again, and did the following.

```
foo <- arrange(foo, desc(split))
foo$split <- as.factor(foo$split)

#> str(foo)
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ split: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1
# $ a    : int  1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
# $ b    : num  6 8 9 10 12 7 8 9 10 11
# $ x    : int  1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
# $ y    : num  1.1 2.1 4.1 5.1 7.1 1 2 3 5 6


q <- ggplot(data = foo, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = split))+
     geom_point(size = 6)

q2 <- ggplot(data = foo, aes(x = a, y = b, colour = split))+
      geom_line()
```

[image]

```
> emo <- ggplot_build(q)$data[[1]] 
> emo
    colour x   y PANEL group
1  #00BFC4 1 1.1     1     2
2  #00BFC4 2 2.1     1     2
3  #00BFC4 3 4.1     1     2
4  #00BFC4 4 5.1     1     2
5  #00BFC4 5 7.1     1     2
6  #F8766D 1 1.0     1     1
7  #F8766D 2 2.0     1     1
8  #F8766D 3 3.0     1     1
9  #F8766D 4 5.0     1     1
10 #F8766D 5 6.0     1     1

> fred <- ggplot_build(q2)$data[[1]]
> fred
    colour x  y PANEL group
1  #00BFC4 1  6     1     2
2  #00BFC4 2  8     1     2
3  #00BFC4 3  9     1     2
4  #00BFC4 4 10     1     2
5  #00BFC4 5 12     1     2
6  #F8766D 1  7     1     1
7  #F8766D 2  8     1     1
8  #F8766D 3  9     1     1
9  #F8766D 4 10     1     1
10 #F8766D 5 11     1     1
```

This object (`emo`) is pretty much identical to `ana` above. For example, the values assigned to the 0 and 1 groups are identical to the ones in `ana`. But the rows for the 0 and 1 groups were stacked the other way around, if you compared the two. The important point is that the 0 group has 1 in group in `ggolot_build()$data[[1]]`. But the points for the group (red points) are on top of the pouts for the 1 group. This is not what the value in group indicate. Then, it seems to me that ggplot is dependent on the values in `unclass()` when it draws figures. In addition, q2 showed the result, which suggest that ggplot used the values in group.

I am sorry for being long. I thought I needed to describe the issue so that my point becomes as clear as possible. The question is how does `ggplot` draw line and dots? As long as I see from the observation above, it uses `unclass` values for points, and group values in `ggolot_build()$data[[1]]` for lines. Does anybody know anything about this issue? Or can anybody suggest what went wrong in this observation? Thank you very much for taking your time till now.

Comment: so to sum up, your question is why, if I draw the red dots first and then I draw the blue dots, why do the red dots not show up on top of the blue dots?

Comment: @rawr I guess the reversed colours in p3 and p4 are confusing. Let me try to rephrase my point. I thought `ggplot` would use the values in group in ggolot_build()$data[[1]] to draw dots and lines. But, I think that is not happening in my observation. Lines seems to be drawn in the number sequence (1 to 2). But, dots aren't. If you look at group in `emo`, the 0 group has 1. If `ggplot` uses the group values, the red dots should have been drawn first, then green dots later. But I do not think that is happening. Then, the question is how ggplot decides which group dots it draws first.